# Cannot connect to Orcacle Database with Python

Tags: python, database, oracle, plsql, robotframework

I try to connect to an Oracle database with Python, but it can't connect.

This is my code:

```
import cx_Oracle

class CustomDatabase(object):

    def getDataFromDatabase(self, connectDB, queryCommand, row):
            conn = cx_Oracle.connect(self.connectDB)
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(self.queryCommand)
            res = cur.fetchone()
            i = 0
            while (i < self.row):
                if cur.rowcount == self.row:
                    print res
                res = cur.fetchone()
                i = i + 1
            cur.close()
            conn.close()
            return res

    a = CustomDatabase()
    b = a.getDataFromDatabase("'Bell', 'pwd1234#', '191.168.1.10:1111/MyName'","select * from Mybook",5)
```

Below is the error I get:

> Error show "AttributeError: 'CustomDatabase' object has no attribute 'connectDB'

Any advice on this matter?

Answer (score 1):

On the first glance it looks like you made a typo

it should be:

```
 def getDataFromDatabase(self, connectDB, queryCommand, row):
     conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connectDB)
     cur = conn.cursor()
     ...
```

instead of:

```
def getDataFromDatabase(self, connectDB, queryCommand, row):
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(self.connectDB)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    ...
```

You are using `self` and the object doesn't have attribute `connectDB`.

Also I can see that later you are using `self.queryCommand` and `self.row` this will fail as well, it should be replaced with `queryCommand` and `row` respectively.